# C++ Lambda as Static Member in CRTP Class Fails to Compile in Visual Studio 15

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++17

I was trying to create a set of policy classes that have different operations which are implemented as static member lambdas. This is so that I could choose between different versions of the same operation based on the given policy and pass the operation to some algorithm such as std::transform.

This lead me to the following design using CRTP, where the base class implements the lambda. Note that C++17 allows one to define constexpr lambdas.

```
namespace test
{
    template <class B>
    struct A
    {
        // The same thing happens if this is static const instead
        static constexpr auto t = [](const auto c) {};
    };

    struct C : A<C>
    {};
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the errors

> error C2888: 'auto ::operator ()(_T1) const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'test'
>
> error C2888: 'auto ::(_T1)': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'test'
>
> error C2888: '::operator unknown-type (__cdecl *)(_T1)(__cdecl *(void) noexcept const)(_T1)': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'test'
>
> ...

followed by the same error for a few different calling conventions.
However, the following code without the surrounding namespace compiles just fine.

```
template <class B>
struct A
{
    static constexpr auto t = [](const auto c) {};
};

struct C : A<C>
{};
```

I've [checked](https://godbolt.org/z/WtjfNi) and the first version compiles on both gcc 8.2 and clang 7 with std=c++17. Am I missing something here or is this a bug? I am using the Community edition of Visual Studio 15.9.4.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
It seems that you can reproduce this issue using only a simple class with a static constexpr generic lambda inside.
This fails to compile:

```
namespace test
{
    struct A
    {
        static constexpr auto t = [](auto c) {};
    };
}
```

But this compiles just fine.

```
struct A
{
    static constexpr auto t = [](auto c) {};
};
```

Lastly, the first version works if the lambda is not generic.

```
namespace test
{
    struct A
    {
        static constexpr auto t = [](char c) {};
    };
}
```

Comment: when gcc and clang agree, and msvc fails, it is generally msvc's fault.

Comment: Strange error message, fails on 19.16 too. Submit a bug report?

Comment: I'll submit a bug report, I just have to gather up all the info to send. Thanks guys.

Comment: The bug report is here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/410676/c-lambda-as-static-member-in-crtp-class-fails-to-c.html

Comment: @S.O. There seems to be a bug report submitted already on this issue. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/192008/generic-lambda-cannot-be-used-within-a-namespace.html. The last comment on that report states that the issue is fixed in VS 15.9 preview 4.0.

Comment: @P.W Thanks for the heads up. I didn't see that when I was looking for existing bug reports.

Comment: @S.O. So the bug still exists in spite of their claim that they fixed it. Am I correct?